# How to get Average from two columns using PIVOT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

In my table I want to get the average value of two columns

```
 PackerID    HeaderID    Price  Quantity  Size  
  1            1           10      10      50  
  2            1           10      10      60  
  3            1           8.5     20      50
  4            2           7       15      60
  5            2           6       30      60
```

Result should be 
   SUM(price*Quantity)/SUM(Quantity) as Average for Same size.

```
HeaderID     Average-50     Average-60 
  1                 9            4.7
```

Price is per 1 quantity* from above table, I want to get average price of Size '50' using PIVOTE.

Comment: How do you want the final result to be displayed?

Comment: I want Size values should be columns and average on price and quantity.Because same size with different price and quantity can available in my table so i want to get average price per size.

Comment: Please edit your original post and show how you want the final result to look.

Comment: Why **must** you use PIVOT? For 100+ sizes? A normalized result will show it in rows, not columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `PIVOT` the result, then you can use something similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select headerid, size,
    sum(price*quantity)/sum(quantity*1.0) perUnit
  from yourtable
  group by headerid, size
) src
pivot
(
  avg(perUnit)
  for size in ([50], [60])
) piv
```

Comment: If i select 10+ columns i need to Group By 10+ columns. That is way i want to ask for Average of multiple columns in PIVOT

Comment: Obviously I am missing something in your requirements, can you try to clarify what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(price * quantity) / sum(quantity)
  from tbl
 where size = 50;

-- result
9.0
```

For all sizes:

```
  select size, sum(price * quantity) / sum(quantity) avg_price_for_size
    from tbl
group by size
order by size;
```